# selinux allow port 8332 porttype

Tags: centos, selinux

selinux is blocking port 8332. Now I want to unlock it. But what porttype do I have to use for an rpc connection? This is the message I get:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 8332.

*****  Plugin connect_ports (85.9 confidence) suggests   *********************

If you want to allow /usr/sbin/php-fpm to connect to network port 8332
Then you need to modify the port type.
Do
# semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 8332
    waarin PORT_TYPE een van de volgende is: dns_port_t, dnssec_port_t, http_port_t, kerberos_port_t, ocsp_port_t.
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I finally found the answer. Just run this command:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```